# Recurrence relation question (counting the number of words of n length)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> An embassy communicates with its home country in code words consisting of a string of n decimal digits. In order to catch errors in transmission, it is agreed that the total number of 3s and 7s in each word should always be odd. Use recurrence relation to find the number of code words are possible.

---

I can go case by case, i.e., one 3 and zero 7 or two 3s and one 7... and find the number of words for each case. However I am not able to generalise the kth term. Since it says use recurrence relation, I'm not able to establish the relation.

I'm very uncomfortable with recurrence relation formulation in general. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify - we are looking for the number of words having length $n$, so if there were no restrictions the answer would be $10^n$ - is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ represent the number of words of length $n$ and $b_n$ represent the non-words that can be formed

$a_1=2$  only legal words are "3" and "7"
$b_1=8$  ( since $a_n+b_n = 10^n$)

When adding an additional digit to your word , if your digit is 3 or 7 you will cause a word to become a non-word and a non-word to become a word , any other digit will not change its status

So the system you need to solve is 
$$ a_n= 8a_{n-1} + 2 b_{n-1}
\\ b_n = 2 a_{n-1} + 8b_{n-1}
\\a_1=2; b_1=8$$
Eliminate $b_n$ using
$b_n-8b_{n-1} = 2 a_{n-1} $
and
$$
a_n-8a_{n-1} = 8a_{n-1}-64a_{n-2} + 2(b_{n-1}-8b{n-2})
\\   =   8a_{n-1}-64a_{n-2} +4a_{n-2} $$

SO ..
$$ a_n = 16a_{n-1}-64a_{n-2}+4a_{n-2}$$

$$a_n-16a_{n-1}+60a_{n-2}=0$$
the characteristic equation is $x^2-16x+60=0$ which has solutions 10 and 6

So try $a_n = C_1 10^n + C_2 6^n$

we know that $a_0=0$ so $C_2=-C_1$

$a_1 = 2$  so $ C_1(10-6)=2\implies C_1 = \frac  12$

finally ...

$$a_n = \frac{10^n - 6^n}2 $$

Comment: I did not understand how you directly arrived at the recurrence relation of a and b.

Comment: There are 10 possibilities for each digit , 2 of them (3 or 7) will result in a word becoming a non-word or vice versa , 8 of them result in no change.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thanks!